# Phonegap and Offline Cache

Tags: cordova, offline-caching

I have been trying out Phonegap and i really love who simple it is to make Phone Apps, if you already know webprogramming.

I am making a app for a website, to make it easy to follow when new posts are online.

I grab the feed and save it to localstorage, 
[localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511892/how-to-work-with-json-feed-stored-in-localstorage-in-phonegap-app)

but how should i cache images?

What are the best way to make your app offline friendly?

Is this the way to do it?
[HTML5 caching manifesto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717485/how-to-cache-images-and-html-files-in-phonegap)

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: I think I solved my own question.

The way i am thinking is that you can foreach the list and save the image to the db, and then when the app is launch again, but are offline, you look if the images is in the db, if it is then show it. Problem solved.

Are you guys doing it another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recommend using html5 cache manifest for a web app, unless you have a known list of images to cache that will hardly change, but in that case I would advise you to add the files locally into your phonegap application source.

In order to cache images in phonegap applications I created this library: [imgcache.js](https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js). It stores images into the filesystem (db should be slower and has smaller disk space available I suppose). If you check out the examples you will see it can also detect when an image fails to load (when you're offline or the server response times out) and replaces it automatically with the cached version.

Comment: Started looking into image caching for my PhoneGap app today and I came upon this. So far your library looks like its going to fit what I need perfectly, thanks!